# deploy a smart contract in production with truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I'm ready to deploy a smart contract in production ethereum blockchain,
may I remove 1_initial_migrations.js from my project?

As far as i can see, when i deployed the contract to rinkeby test network also the Migrations.sol has been delpoyed, but i do not understand what is the scope of this additional contract.

tnx for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Do not remove 1_initial_migrations.js . It is there to deploy the migrations.sol smart contract.

The Migrations contract keeps track of which migrations were done on the current network.

Inside the migrations folder, you will see a file called 1_initial_migration.js The 1 in the filename is the reference number of a migration.

Once you have created a couple of contracts, and want to deploy them using truffle migrate, you can create another migration file called 2_name_of_migration.js. Once the migration is done, Truffle will store that  reference number 2 in the Migrations contract